# Can I Hide images from bundle resource or framework in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, resourcebundle, ios-frameworks

I have a project converted to a framework, and a bundle resource which has many images and storyboard. Everything works perfectly fine. My question is can I hide or protect these images from being replaced in the bundle resource? I want to give access to only some images, rest of them i want to hide it. is it possible?

Comment: Or may be how can I add these images into my framework without using bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert image to NSData, encrypt, compress it.  You can also convert it to base 64, encrypt it, etc.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. But im not sure how to do this. I have almost 300 images (iPhone 1x,2x iPad 1x,2x) in the bundle. How will i take these image and encrypt and set back to bundle? how will it look when I open the bundle?

Comment: But the encryption key and decrypt methods also need to be supplied.

Comment: @mChopsey: You just need to create a lab project that will take your individual image file, apply encryption technology of your chosen, and save it back to individual file.  And then just include those encrypted files to your bundle instead of the image files.  In your real app, you need to decrypt these files whenever there is a call to get any of those images.

Comment: @Zaph: Yes, but one can come up with certain creative ways to obfuscate the key.  It probably would not deter a sophisticated individual.