# Is it possible to hide files in resource bundle?

Tags: ios, bundle

Is it possible to hide files in resource bundle ? (created in Xcode7)

Inside resource bundle, There are only png images.

I want to upload this bundle to public place (like github),
and I do not want other ones to access image files in the bundle directly.
(inside Xcode, outside Xcode as well)

I even want to no one check file names in a bundle for a security reason.

But, is this possible ?

ps. I found similar question [Can I Hide images from bundle resource or framework in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421888/can-i-hide-images-from-bundle-resource-or-framework-in-ios)
but, this link is for encrypting some files in bundle, not for 'hiding' every files in the bundle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I Hide images from bundle resource or framework in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421888/can-i-hide-images-from-bundle-resource-or-framework-in-ios)

Comment: Since the resource bundle is just a directory structure with some JSON file there is not way to hide them. The other post you linked to seems to be your only option.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You seem to both want to make something public and some part of it private, why? If you just want a free private Git repository you can use [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org) for unlimited private repositories.

Comment: zaph : just because some pictures in a bundle, we do not have copyright to release on pubic place.. ;;;;